# Doctrine2 - Multiple OneToMany to the same entity in the same entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

This could be a problem with how I design my entity or my lack of knowledge in assosiations between entity.

Parent entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Item", mappedBy="groupContainer")
 */
private $groupA;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Item", mappedBy="building")
 */
private $groupB;
```

Child entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GroupContainer", inversedBy="groupA")
 */
private $groupContainer;
```

From my current understanding of Doctrine, when you have a OneToMany, doctrine cannot store the foreign key in the "parent" table, it makes the child hold the key as to avoid a csv value.

Since that is the case, I don't think it's possible to do what I'm trying to accomplish, since the child entry would need two ManyToOne declaration, one for groupA and one for groupB.

How can I resolve my conflict?

Comment: It is a bit unclear (to me at least) what your actual problem (conflict) here is. Why wouldn't you create the two needed $groupAContainer and $groupBContainer declarations into the child entity if you clearly have two separate associations? You can always create an additional entity variable that contains the merged result of those two associations if that is what you need (?)